# Where is undefined method called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, better-errors-gem

I have a `decisions` resource, which is nested under a `groups` resource. `has_many` and `belongs_to` have been defined in the models.

```
resources :groups do
  resources :decisions
end
```

...and I have an edit form at this path:

**/groups/:group_id/decisions/:id/edit(.:format)**

I'm getting an error in my Rspec test:

> Failure/Error: put :update, {:id => decision.to_param, :decision =>
>   valid_attributes, group_id: decision.group.id}, valid_session
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `decision_url' for #DecisionsController:0x007ffeb23482e0>

And when I navigate to the form in my development environment, I get a similar error:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_decision_path(@group, @decision) %>
```

> NoMethodError at /groups/6/decisions/5/edit
>
> > undefined method `decision_path' for #<#:0x007fd1ff569130>

I'm using the `'better_errors'` gem, and it cites the first line of the `form_for` for the no method error:

```
<%= form_for(@decision) do |f| %>
```

I don't have `'decision_url'` anywhere in my code. What am I missing? Shouldn't `form_for` know where to PUT the update? There's a valid path for it at:

**/groups/:group_id/decisions/:id(.:format)**

Here is the part of the log that looks most exciting:

```
Rendered decisions/_form.html.erb (6.5ms)
  Rendered decisions/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (7.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `decision_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd5d98527b0>:0x007fd5d400d618>:
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:220:in `polymorphic_method'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:134:in `polymorphic_path'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:466:in `apply_form_for_options!'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:434:in `form_for'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `decision_url` call that it was complaining about:

```
if @decision.update(decision_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @decision), notice: 'Decision was successfully updated.' }
```

Changing `@decision` to `group_decision_path(@group, @decision)` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified your nested resources like this:

```
resource groups do
  resource decisions
end
```

The routing, however, should be specified using symbols, like this:

```
resource :groups do
  resource :decisions
end
```

Make sure your models also have the proper relationships defined:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :decisions
end

class Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the typo. The resources were/are symbols in my code. The relationships were/are defined as per your answer. Thanks!